# How to remove ad "Double Click"

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flash

Hi all I am developing a website in wordpress and I have to create a video playlist.

I am using the [Flash Player](https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/wp-flash-player) plugin for creating it. At starting it works quite perfectly but from quite some days in every video there is an ad coming in it featuring ***Doble Click*** video.

How can I remove this ad from the video. is it possible to remove this ad. Here is the [demo link](http://www.apptha-demo.com/wp_product_demo/) for the plugin.

Can anybody have any idea how to remove this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is only free for non-commercial use, which is why it has the logo and advertisement. To remove this, you need to pay for a licensed copy. Any other means of subverting the advert is illegal.

Further info: http://www.hdflvplayer.net/hd-flv-player-features.php

Comment: But when I started using it, it is working fine without an advertisement. so how can it is showing afterwords.